# NuGet uninstall Foundation 3 Core files error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I am trying to uninstall Foundation 3 Core files from my ASP.NET MVC project with Manage NuGet Packages, in Visual Studio 2012.

When I click uninstall I get this error:

> Unable to uninstall 'Foundation3_Core 3.2' because 'Foundation3_MVC4 2.2.32' depend(s) on it.

What I have to do to uninstall it from my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted from packages.config wrong entry for Foundation, and after that I was able to uninstall it with NuGet.